# Setting a value dynamically for data attributes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I use data attributes extensively for managing data in client side events. Is it possible to assign value dynamically to a data attribute using javascript or jquery?

```
<li data-class_value="somevalue" class="myclass"></li>


$('.myclass').click(function(){
   $(this).data('class_value') = "new value";
});
```

The above javascript code throws the error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment".

Could someone please tell me how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to do

```
 $(this).data('class_value', "new value");
```

Answer (score 33):

I believe the other answers to this question would only set the data object on that element within jQuery.

If you need to set the actual HTML data-* attribute, you'd need to use this:

```
$(this).attr("data-class_value", "new value");
```

Beware of retrieving HTML5 data-* attributes this way as well, as although you can use the shortcut `$(this).data("class_value");` to retrieve them, subsequent retrievals will use the cached value in the jQuery data object.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5):

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

Source: [jQuery caching of data attributes](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-data-caching-of-data-attributes)

Comment: That caching of data attributes ate few hours, thanks!

Comment: How do you work around that caching issue? I tried `$(this).removeAttr("data-class_value", "new value");` but of course it doesn't work. Any clues?

Comment: @kevllar `removeAttr` only takes one argument. So it won't set the new value for you. You'd need to use `attr` instead.

Comment: @jjeaton I'm trying to set the attribute then remove it... But its not working because its being cached... I tried `attr` but no joy

Comment: @kevllar if you want to remove the data from the cache AND remove the attribute in the DOM, you'd want this: `$(this).removeData("class_value").removeAttr("data-class_value")`

Comment: @jjeaton Looks like I wasn't targeting the dom elements correctly. I used `attr` and then `removeAttr` and that seemed to work in the end. No need for removeData. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).data('class_value','new value') ;`

**[`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)**