# change html5 variable with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to change the value of an html variable using jquery.

For instance,

```
  <div id="smile" data-count="2"></div>
```

how would I change the variable data-count to 3 using jquery

Comment: That is not an "HTML5 variable" (there is no such thing). That's an HTML5 data attribute, and you can update it like any other attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting a value dynamically for data attributes using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163234/setting-a-value-dynamically-for-data-attributes-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#smile').data('count', 3);
```

or:

```
$('#smile').attr('data-count', 3);
```

---

You can store the `data` value in a variable and then increase it like this:

```
var data = parseInt($('#smile').attr('data-count'), 10);

$('#smile').attr('data-count', data+1);
```

Comment: Note that `$('#smile').data('count', 3);` doesn't change the attribute of the element, it only updates jQuery's internal data storage.

Comment: is it possible to just increment data-count by 1 without having to retrieve the data and manually adding one and then updating?

Comment: what does the number 10 do?

Comment: @KwaasiDjin: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters. And no, it's not possible to increment the value without getting it first.

Comment: @KwaasiDjin It's the `radix` which is a number (from 2 to 36) that represents the numeral system to be used, i.e. 2 for binary, 10 for decimal, 16 for hexadecimal. You can used @Felix Kling reference link for more details about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#smile').attr('data-count', 3);
```