# Adding data-0 attribute to div

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I want to add this..

```
data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-500="background-position:0px -250px;"
```

..to a div called 'section-1'. This is my code called within my document ready function, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
if($(window).width() > 767){
  $('#section-1').attr('0', 'background-position:0px 0px;');
  $('#section-1').attr('500', 'background-position:0px -250px;');
}
```

My css looks like this

```
#section-1{
  background-image:url(test.jpg); width:100%; height:500px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px){
  #section-1{
    background-image:url(test.jpg); background-size:100%; height:500px;
  }
}
```

It's for some parallax in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: Be aware, you should use `window.matchMedia` not `window.width()` to completly fit  with CSS media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attribute is called `data-0` so give the complete attribute name

```
$('#section-1').attr('data-0', 'background-position:0px 0px;');
```

Comment: I see that works, but only when i use the Firebug, not when i try to view to source, and it doesn't parallax? Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Sultenhest: Use a tool like the Chrome F12 DOM inspector as View Source tends to show the original server HTML file *before* any code is run on the page :)

Answer (score 2):

when you use the [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function you have to put the "data" prefix too.

if you would use the [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function you can write it as you did

so:

```
$('#section-1').attr('data-0', 'background-position:0px 0px;');
```

or

```
$('#section-1').data('0', 'background-position:0px 0px;');
```

greetings timotheus

Comment: Your second option is incorrect. It will not store data as an attribute *(only read it from an attribute)*. Data will store it in a browser lookup dictionary behind the scenes.

Comment: it seems to be working for me and others? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7163234/2645202

Comment: You are referencing irrelevant answers. `data()` *will not* change the *attribute* `data-` value in the HTML.

Comment: You should have stopped at "thanks for this info" :P Just delete the incorrect second option and remove all reference to `.data()` to make it a correct answer. Consider yourself fortunate to get 2 upvotes from the ignorant masses.